# Passing RAILS_ENV into Torquebox without using a Deployment Descriptor

Tags: deployment, jruby, torquebox

I am wondering if there is a way to pass a value for **RAILS_ENV** directly into the Torquebox server without going through a deployment descriptor; similar to how I can pass properties into Java with the -D option.

I have been wrestling with various deployment issues with Torquebox over the past couple weeks. I think a large part of the problem has to do with packaging the gems into the Knob file, which is the most practical way for managing them on a Window environment. I have tried archive deployment and expanded deployment; with and without external deployment descriptor.

- With an external deployment descriptor, I found the packaged Gem dependencies were not properly deployed and I received errors about missing dependencies.
- When expanded, I had to fudge around a lot with the dependencies and what got included in the Knob, but eventually I got it to deploy. However, certain files in the expanded Knob were marked as failed (possible duplicate dependencies?), but they did not affect the overall deployment. The problem was when the server restarted, deployment would fail the second time mentioning it could not redeploy one of the previously failed files.

The only one I have found to work consistently for me is archive without external deployment descriptor. However, I still need a way to tell the application in which environment it is running. I have different Torquebox instances for each environment and they only run the one application, so it would be fairly reasonable to configure this at the server level.

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I finally came to was to pass in **RAILS_ENV** as a Java property to the Torquebox server and then to set `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to this value in the Rails *boot.rb* initializer.

**Step 1: Set Java Property**

First, you will need to set a Rails Environment java property for your Torquebox server. To keep with standard Java conventions, I called this *rails.env*.

Dependent on your platform and configuration, this change will need to be made in one of the following scripts:

- *Using JBoss Windows Service Wrapper:* service.bat
- *Standalone environment:* standalone.conf.bat (Windows) or standalone.conf (Unix)
- *Domain environment:*: domain.conf.bat (Windows) or domain.conf (Unix)

Add the following line to the appropriate file above to set this Java property:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Drails.env=staging
```

The `-D` option is used for setting Java system properties.

**Step 2: Set ENV['RAILS_ENV'] based on Java Property**

We want to set the RAILS_ENV as early as possible, since it is used by a lot of Rails initialization logic. Our first opportunity to inject application logic into the Rails Initialization Process is *boot.rb*.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-boot-rb

The following line should be added to the top of *boot.rb*:

```
# boot.rb (top of the file)
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ENV_JAVA['rails.env'] if defined?(ENV_JAVA) && ENV_JAVA['rails.env']
```

This needs to be the first thing in the file, so Bundler can make intelligent decisions about the environment.

As you can see above, a seldom mentioned feature of JRuby is that it conveniently exposes all Java system properties via the `ENV_JAVA` global map (mirroring the `ENV` ruby map), so we can use it to access our Java system property.

We check that `ENV_JAVA` is defined (i.e. JRuby is being used), since we support multiple deployment environments.

I force the rails.env property to be used when present, as it appears that *RAILS_ENV* already has a default value at this point.

Comment: Awesome post. Thank you for the detailed guide.